# angular 6 - http get api from url

Tags: json, angular6, httpmodule

I want get json from an url (url is a json code from w3school site that I write it in codes.)

I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50759725/http-get-call-in-angular-6).

My code is

**app.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    {{ title  | uppercase }}
  </h1>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let json of Jsons">
        <td>{{ json.Name }}</td>
        <td>{{ json.City }}</td>
        <td>{{ json.Country }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component , OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { JsonService } from './json.service';
import { Json } from './json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'nowian';
  jsons: Json[];

  constructor(private jsonService: JsonService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this
      .jsonService
      .getjson()
      .subscribe((data: Json[]) => {
        this.jsons = data;
    });
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { JsonService } from './json.service';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [JsonService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**json.ts**

```
export interface Json{
    Name: string;
    City: string;
    Country: string;
}
```

**json.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class JsonService {

  url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getjson(){
    return this
          .http
          .get(`${this.url}`);
  }
}
```

But it does not work!!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What happens when you run your code? What did you expect to happen instead? Are you getting any errors? If so, please [edit] your question and include any errors and stack traces.

Comment: That's a lot of code you posted. To make it easier to figure out what goes wrong, can you please [edit]  your question and remove all code that's not relevant? Can you make your question a [mcve] please? You may also want to take the [tour] of the site and learn how to ask a good question, to get more answers.

Comment: Hi, no error happend,
Just don't show json in table.